# Symfony2 swiftmailer file spool: Mails stay in status sending with attachments

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I send my emails in symfony2 with the file spool. Now I wanted to add some attachments to the mails. The mails stay with the filename "xxxxxx.sending". If I remove the spool and send them directly it's working.

Perhaps someone had the same problem already?

Comment: How about some code? Do you execute the `swiftmailer:spool:send` command?

Comment: Yeah sure. Like I said without attachments everything was working fine. Then I added some attachments it was not sending the mails anymore but it changes the filename to "xxxxx.sending" like normal but doesn't finish. Without the spool it's sending the mails with attachments. I don't know what kind of code could be interesting in this case. The attachments are added correctly to the mails (without spool it's working)

Comment: Okay I solved the problem. I was running the command with a cronjob and didn't check it by hand (stupid me). When I executed it by hand I saw that the path to the attachment was wrong. So the attachment path for sending the mail directly from php is different then if I want to send the mails with "swiftmailer:spool:send".
Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need to specify the attachment path when you send spool messages?

Comment: I don't remember but I think it was related to relative paths. So I used absolute path for attachments.